# Lagrangian with Infinite solutions?

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to minimize the quantity
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2\right) + x_Ax_B$$
where $A$ and $B$ are fixed such that $1\leq A<B\leq k$. We have the constraint
$$\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=1$$
and non-negativity constraints on each $x_i$. I know that if I use Lagrange multipliers (we have continuous partial derivatives), I will need to check the boundary / endpoints, but by the nature of the problem I am working on, that will not be too hard. Anyways, I have the first order conditions:
\begin{align*}
x_A+x_B+\lambda &= 0\\
x_i+\lambda &= 0\quad\text{ for $i\neq A,B$}
\end{align*}
Plugging into the constraint using $x_A+x_B=-\lambda=x_i$ and simplifying gives me
$$(k-1)(x_A+x_B)=1\implies \lambda=-\frac{1}{k-1}$$
Here is where I am confused. It seems to me that $x_A$ and $x_B$ can take on any values; it only matters that they sum up to $-\frac{1}{k-1}$. I've never really seen a Lagrangian give a solution with a free variable, so I am wondering if it is valid.

Comment: Though I am no expert in optimisation, it looks correct to me.

Comment: You didn’t solve your constraint correctly.  You should’ve derived $(k-1)(-\lambda)=0$ which doesn’t imply $\lambda=-\frac{1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @Mnifldz That is surely a typo. Differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to the multiplier and setting every $x_{i} = \lambda$ except the $x_{A}, x_{B}$ variables, whose sum equals $\lambda$, you get $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_{k} - 1 = x_{1} + \dots + x_{A} + \dots + x_{B} + \dots + x_{k} - 1 = (k - 1) \lambda - 1 = 0$$